# groovy.json.JsonException: How to parse JSON string containing another JSON string?

Tags: python, json, groovy

Suppose I have a JSON string containing another JSON string within it.

```
data = {
   "a": "...",
   "b" : "Very long JSON string",
   "c" : "Very long JSON string",
   "d" : "...",
}

json.dumps(data)
```

The following`jsonStr` is generated as above using Python.

```
jsonStr = "{
  "a": "...",
  "b" : "Very long JSON string",
  "c" : "Very long JSON string",
  "d" : "...",
   :
}"
```

When I try to parse it by

```
json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(jsonStr)
```

I get the following error.

```
groovy.json.JsonException: Expected a value on line: 1, column: 1344513.
But got an unterminated object.
```

What would be a good way to handle this situation?

Would applying the Base64 encoding to the JSON strings sound a good idea?

Comment: Are those "Very long JSON string" not properly quoted?  Please provide an example, that shows the actual error.

Comment: I think the `json.dumps(data)` part takes care of that.

Comment: Please provide failing code.  The jsonStr is not valid groovy.

Comment: Actually, the groovy snippet I have provided is a part of Jenkins pipeline script. `def jsonStr = waitForWebhook hook` is the actual script where I am using Webhook Step plugin to receive the result of some external process and simply returns the JSON string generated by the python script above.

Comment: My guess is, that the JSON-in-JSON just is some banged together string and there are quoting errors.  Without an actual failing example i dont see how we ever can go beyond the "guess work" level?